whereBetween con key compuesta ORM laravel
Estoy intentando obtener un detalle de movimientos por cuenta contable, de la tabla detalle_movimientos con su saldo:

Con el siguiente codigo casi lo logro:
$detalle_movimientos = DetalleMovimientos::whereRaw("CONCAT(pd.cta, pd.scta, pd.sscta) between '$cuentaInic' and '$cuentaFin' ")->get();

Sin embargo lo que quiero obtener es un array como el siguiente:
$detalle_movimientos = [  

        102 1 1 => [
            ['cargo' => 80, 'abono'  => 0, 'saldo'  => 80],
            ['cargo' => 0, 'abono'  => 50, 'saldo'  => 30]
        ],
        
        102 1 2 => [
            ['cargo' => 90, 'abono'  => 0, 'saldo'  => 90],
            ['cargo' => 0, 'abono'  => 61, 'saldo'  => 29]
        ]

        105 1 0 => [
            ['cargo' => 20, 'abono'  => 0, 'saldo'  => 20]
        ]

        105 2 0 => [
            ['cargo' => 0, 'abono'  => 5, 'saldo'  => -5]
        ]
    ];

No se si sea posblie. Ayuda!

puedes darnos que es lo que obtienes y que es lo que esperas obtener? estoy casi seguro de que eso lo deberias de organizar con un sort by Cuenta Asc, subCuenta Asc, subSubCuenta Asc y los datos deberian ser algo como: [ 102,105] ... nadamas ...

Ya modifique la pregunta, espero haberme explicado un poco mejor.

creo que esta mal, un select tiene dos partes: el cuerpo y la condicional... entonces CONCAT por que lo pones en la condicion??? no deberia de estar en el cuerpo?
